# Apply css Animation to Div when Array.map added or remove div in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**For reference**, check out this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cufbw4?file=index.tsx)

I have css animation `@keyframes` class..

```
 /*
    Animation classes.
 */

.example-enter {
   animation: flasher 0.5s;
}

@keyframes flasher{
   from {
      opacity: 0.2;
   }
   to {
     opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

I am applying this `.example-enter` css class to div when `array.map` is having new added data. like below..

```
<div className="example-enter"> ... </div>
```

The question is when I added new Array to state, react will create new div, and gives animation to last added div only. But I want very first element to be animated, not last one when added new state to array.

You can check out demo in above stackblitz link to check out more details and see there when we add new list only last div is animated but i want to animate very first element to animate because that first div element is i added to array. using.. `setTodoState( prev => [newTodoState, ...prev ]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is on this line, you're using `index` as key for your `LineItem`.

```js
todoState.map((item, index) => <LineItem key={index} todoList={item} index={index}/>)
```

*React does not recomment using indexes for keys, read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).*

---

You need to have some sort of **id to uniquely identify your todo items** and use that `id` as key when you do your `todoState.map((item) => ...`. So you'll have to make your todo item as an `object` and not a `string`.

In your `TodoForm`, we'll add a `generateId` and use this functions return value for our new todo's `id`.

**TodoForm.tsx**

```js
function generateId() {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084248/8062659
  return Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
}
```

```js
const sendTodoItem = (e) => {
  if(todoInput.trim().length > 0){
    const text = todoInput.trim();
    const id = generateId();

    addNewTodoState({ text , id }); // notice here
    setIsDisabled(false);
    setTodoInput('');
  }else{
    setIsDisabled(true);
  }
}
```

Now on you `TodoListLineItem`, we'll remove the `index` from `map` and use the current todo's `id` as key.

**TodoListLineItem.tsx**

```js
todoState.map((item) => <LineItem key={item.id} todoList={item}/>)
```

We also have to update your `Line-Item` to display the `text` property of the current todo.

**Line-Item.tsx**

```js
<p>{todoList.text}</p>
```

Check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-j9trbw) for a demo.

--

Because we're using now an `object` as a todo item, I believe you should also make changes on some parts of the app, like the model and the delete feature. But the changes above should be sufficient to achieve what you want as described on your post.

Comment: When item is removed, then how to apply to that only one selected div to animate?

Comment: That's when things gets complicated. I would suggest [React Transition Group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group) library for that.

Comment: Thank you. I will checkout it. but now I applied custom logic to add new css removeClass for some period of time and animate removed item div. Can you have best recommended react animation library for large scale production ready app development.

Comment: I only tried React Transition Group - I believe it's a good choice! You can check its repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group).

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to add the animation class with useEffect and remove it after the duration of the animation.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const YourApp = props => {
 
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false)
  const [todoState, setTodoState] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnimate( true )
    setTimeout( () => { setAnimate( false ) }, 500 )
  }, [todoState])


  return <div className={ animate ? "example-enter" : null } > ... </div>
}
```

Each time you update todoState, it will apply the animation class for 0.5s basically.